# System reserved partition of windows 10 no longer hidden

Tags: windows, boot

I have a dual booted laptop with Ubuntu and windows 10. After the installation and fixing some boot error, when I boot into Windows 10 and open file explorer, "System Reserved" partition is marked with "D:" drive path. I think deleting the drive path may cause some boot errors so, is there any method to hide the partition from file explorer without causing errors?

Comment: open disk management and remove the drive letter: http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/

Comment: Won't it cause any boot errors?

Comment: no, by default it never has a drive letter

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The SYSTEM drive, never has a drive letter by default. Open disk management

[image]

right click on `SYSTEM` partition and select `Change Drive Letters and Paths`

[image]

and now click on `Remove`

[image]